# How to add indices in an array in jolt transformation

Tags: transformation, jolt

I am trying to modify my input and add an id for each object with '-indexNum' but this seems not working.Here I m posting my code.

My input,

```
 {
   "employees": [{
        "f_name": "tom",
        "l_name": "smith"
    },
    {
        "f_name": "don",
        "l_name": "jones"
    }
 ]
}
```

Expected o/p:

```
{
"employees": [{
    "firstName": "tom",
    "lastName": "smith",
    "test": "emp-"
}, {
    "firstName": "don",
    "lastName": "jones",
    "test": "emp-"
}]
}
```

My spec,

```
[{
    "operation": "shift",
    "spec": {
        "employees": {
            "*": {
                "f_name": "employees[&1].firstName",
                "l_name": "employees[&1].lastName"
            }
        }
    }
},
{
    "operation": "modify-overwrite-beta",
    "spec": {
        "employees": {
            "*": {
                "test": "=concat('emp-',)"
            }
        }
    }
}]
```

I am trying to modify my input and add an id for each object with '-indexNum'.Can anyone please suggest me help.Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Spec

```
[
  {
    "operation": "shift",
    "spec": {
      "employees": {
        "*": {
          "$": "employees[&1].employeeNum",
          "f_name": "employees[&1].firstName",
          "l_name": "employees[&1].lastName"
        }
      }
    }
  },
  {
    "operation": "modify-overwrite-beta",
    "spec": {
      "employees": {
        "*": {
          "employeeNum": "=concat('emp-',@(1,employeeNum))"
        }
      }
    }
  }
]
```